# Not getting crashlytics crash report in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, crashlytics-android

I have integrated 'Carshlytics' in a 'Xamarin-Android' project, I followed all steps given [here](https://github.com/azchohfi/Crashlytics.Droid) but its not giving crash reports. I have configured same account with native Android and I got this working but it's not working with 'Xamarin-Android'.

Please suggest me the right path for this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the document about [Xamarin.Android architecture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) :

> `Xamarin.Android` applications run within the Mono execution environment. This execution environment runs side-by-side with the Android Runtime (ART) virtual machine.

If the exception happened in `ART`, the `Carshlytics` should be work, but if it happened in mono, the `Carshlytics` will not work.

You could try to add these handlers for exceptions :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironmentOnUnhandledException;
```